Slow Borg backup, excessive wall time (not CPU)
I am perplexed by why Borg backup is requiring such a large amount of real time. I thought this might be related to the source files being stored in the btrfs filesystem, but creating a tar archive of the same data doesn't insert an extra six or so hours of wall time
/mnt/btrfs/2024-11-05 contains around 400Gb, around 300k files. A borg archive of a previous snapshot /mnt/btrfs/2024-11-01 has already been created, and the updated files amount to around 100Mb, which Borg  deduplicates. But why is this so slow? (in terms of real time, not CPU time)
time tar cf /dev/null /mnt/btrfs/2024-11-05/

reports real: 6m27, user: 14s, sys: 2m15
time borg create /mnt/borg/test/2024-11-05 /mnt/btrfs/2024-11-05/

reports real: 8h30, user: 2h30. I can understand the 2h30 spent de-duplicating, checksumming and decrypting, but why the extra six hours of wall time?
Any suggestions other than getting rid of the  hard disks in favour of SSD? (The btrfs has metadata on SSD but the data on hard disk. /mnt/borg is a hard disk formatted ext4. )

On Linux,  profile what exactly on CPU during run with something like perf record -a -F 999 --  borg create /mnt/borg/test/2025-11-05 /mnt/btrfs/2025-11-05/   and while it runs get statistics on file system latency with  btrfsdist   and ext4dist  from bcc-tools (from different terminals).  When it completes, or you interrupt perf after a few minutes,  report on the top symbols with  perf report    and share the three results with us.
